# Wordpress two Loops on Index

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

What I am attempting to do is run two separate loops on my index page in Wordpress:

One that does NOT HAVE posts from category 5

And

One that ONLY HAS posts from category 5

I keep ending up with close to the right results but where the first loop shows what I want in the second loop (which baffles me) and a bunch of other anomalies.

Here is the code:

Loop 1:

```
<?php $blogPreview = new WP_Query('cat=-5'); ?>
<?php if ( $blogPreview->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $blogPreview->have_posts() ) : $blogPreview->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content-index', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    Sorry, but there are currently no posts in the blog!
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Loop 2 (slightly below loop 1 in my markup):

```
<?php $testimonials = new WP_Query('cat=5'); ?>
<?php if ( $testimonials->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $testimonials->have_posts() ) : $testimonials->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content-index-testimonials', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
     Sorry, but there are currently no posts in the blog!
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any Ideas?  Thanks in advance

Ok so that was fixed by removing "the_post()" from the loops.

Now I cannot exclude this category for the life of me, I have tried all the following:

```
<?php $blogPreview = new WP_Query('cat=-5'); ?>
<?php $blogPreview = new WP_Query(array('category__not_in'=>5)); ?>
<?php $blogPreview = new WP_Query('category__not_in'=>array(5)); ?>
```

are all failing to do it.

Comment: Alright so the original problem is fixed, but now I can not for the life of me exclude a category, edited the main post to show the new problem

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  As for the edit, it's probably worth asking a new question so the two problems don't get confused.  For what it's worth, I can't see anything wrong with the first line you tried.  For the second and third, you may need `array()` twice, so `$blogPreview = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 5 ) ) );`.  That's how I read the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not certain, but I suspect it might have something to do with the call to

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
```

after you've already called it for the `WP_Query` objects (eg `$testimonials->the_post();`).  I think that call would be using the global `$wp_query` value, and overwriting the values set in your previous call.  Try deleting it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I have another problem in my comments if you'd like to take a look at that

Answer (score 3):

In both loops remove " the_post();" because you've already called $testimonials->the_post();

```
<?php $testimonials = new WP_Query('cat=5'); ?>
<?php if ( $testimonials->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $testimonials->have_posts() ) : $testimonials->the_post(); ?>
        <?php // i.e. You can call here, the_title(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content-index-testimonials', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>Sorry, but there are currently no posts in the blog!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, gave you a plus one, but had to give the Hobo the answer since he came first.  Have another question in my comments if you have time to look at that.

Comment: Welcome and that's 100% fair and I appreciate that and Hobo deserves one from me too.